# Python Random Numbers using commas

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm wondering how I can choose a random number from commas?

Here's an example configuration file:

```
{
    "number": 10,
    "thisisatest": "yes"
}
```

If I use the 'number' variable in my Python script, obviously it's 10 however I want to add more numbers than just 10, how would I do that?

Comment: configuration file; Is this json? What does your code look like? Too many unknowns here to help.

Comment: Please show us your current code so we can figure out what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list:

```
{
    "number": [10, 20, 30, 40],
    "thisisatest": "yes"
}
```

and then use `random.choice`